# PCRE Regex - Match everything to the first pipe not enclosed by square brackets

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following line of text, where I am trying to extract everything up to the first pipe character that is not enclosed in square brackets.

```
action=search sourcetype=audittrail [ localop | stats count | eval search_id = replace("$top10_drilldown_sid$", "^remote_[^_]*_", "") | table search_id ] [ localop | stats count | eval earliest = $top10_drilldown_earliest$ - 86400 | table earliest ] latest="$top10_drilldown_latest$" | stats values(savedsearch_name) AS search_name
```

Expected output:

```
action=search sourcetype=audittrail [ localop | stats count | eval search_id = replace("$top10_drilldown_sid$", "^remote_[^_]*_", "") | table search_id ] [ localop | stats count | eval earliest = $top10_drilldown_earliest$ - 86400 | table earliest ] latest="$top10_drilldown_latest$"
```

i.e. Everything but the trailing `| stats values(savedsearch_name) AS search_name`

Following some lookaround examples, I could (nearly) get what I needed using a JavaScript Regex expression

`/.*\|(?![^\[]*\])/g`
But this didn't translate well into a PCRE-compatible expression that worked (plus I want to capture everything up to, but not including, the first pipe).

From what I've read, the nested square brackets in the first bracketed set may be a complication that can't be worked around? There would only be one level of nested brackets in any given set (e.g. `[..[]..]` or `[..[]..[]..]`)

I admit that I don't think I've got my head fully around positive & negative lookarounds, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are sure that the brackets are balanced, use [`^(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^|])+\K\|`](https://regex101.com/r/6ZJpqN/1). However, that does not have to be so, your string might as well contain `\]`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - Lots of new concepts in this one for me. I'll try to get my head around it. Looking at the example you sent, I realise I didn't include what I would expect to get. I'll edit it now.

Comment: [Remove `\K\|`](https://regex101.com/r/6ZJpqN/2)

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - This worked a treat! I had to make a minor adjustment to grab all the leading characters `^(?<base_query>.*(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^|])+)\|` Now to find some kind of Rosetta Stone to decypher this! How do I give you credit/mark as solved here?

Comment: Well, if you add `.*` at the beginning that kind of ruins the logic. My pattern is easy to read: match the start of the string, then match any `[...]` substrings with balanced `[...]` inside, or a char other than `|`, the whole is repeated 1 or more times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of situation, it's more efficient to match all that isn't the delimiter than trying to split:

```
(?=[^|])[^][|]*(?:(\[[^][]*+(?:(?1)[^][]*)*+])[^][|]*)*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/FMr8fo/3)

details:

```
(?=[^|]) # lookahead: ensure there's at least one non pipe character at the
         # current position, the goal is to avoid empty match.
[^][|]* # all that isn't a bracket or a pipe
(?:
    (  # open the capture group 1: describe a bracket part
        \[
         [^][]*+ # all that isn't a bracket (note that you don't have to care
                 # about of the pipe here, you are between brackets)
         (?:
             (?1)  # refer to the capture group 1 subpattern (it's a recursion
                   # since this reference is in the capture group 1 itself)
             [^][]* 
         )*+
         ]
    ) # close the capture group 1
    [^][|]*
)*
```

If you need empty parts too, you can rewrite it like this:

```
(?=[^|])[^][|]*(?:(\[[^][]*+(?:(?1)[^][]*)*+])[^][|]*)*|(?<=\|)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great breakdown - I'll give this a try now :-)

Comment: @Arrjo: refresh the page, I made a typo (corrected now).